# setcookie not setting for the following code

Tags: php, cookies

set cookie is not setting the value for the following code.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    ob_start();
    unset($_SESSION['adminname']);
    session_destroy();
    if(isset($_COOKIE['adminremember_me'])) {
        $past = time() - 100;
        setcookie('adminremember_me', gone, $past);
    }

    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
?>
```

Cookie is not deleting as setcookie donot works though an error message is not displayed.
Interesting part is that i have another file with same code structure but with different cookie name for normal user logout and that one works.

**I moved the admin logout file which was in (htdocs/site/admin/)to (htdocs/site) and now logout works!!! seriously what change didit make?**

Comment: @jycr753 check my edit--the code was there, but his formatting kept it from showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple cookies with the same name but different paths. So if you script is in /folder1/folder2/mypage.php, you can have 1 cookie with the path /folder1 and another with the path /folder1/folder2, and both cookies could have the same name.

My guess is the cookie you are trying to delete belongs to a different path (by default, if you don't specify a path, then it assumes the folder that the script is in). To delete it, you will have to manually set the path parameter to match that of the cookie. For example:

```
setcookie('adminremember_me', gone, $past, "/");
```

or

```
setcookie('adminremember_me', gone, $past, "/folder1/");
```

To see what the path is on the existing cookie, you need to use your browser's cookie viewer to see what path is set on it.

Edit: to answer the question in your edit, when you moved the location of your logout file, you moved it to be in the same folder as the path that was set on the cookie (so the default value was now the same). If you want to move the script back to the old location, just explicity set the path to whatever the folder was where it worked